# Возможен ли доступ к элементам struct без прямого обращения к ним через точку?

Tags: c

Предположим, у меня есть следующая структура:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} MKMapPoint;
```

**Можно ли получить доступ к первому и второму элементу этой структуры без непосредственного обращения к элементам этой структуры через точку (.)?**

P.S. Я пытаюсь узнать, возможен ли в C какой-то более общий способ обращения к элементам C-структуры?

---

Пример:

```
MKMapPoint point;
point.x; // значение x
point.y; // значение y
```

Можно ли получить значения point.x и point.y без непосредственного обращения к point.x и к point.y?

Comment: Можно, но изврат.

    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef struct {
      double x;
      double y;
    } MKMapPoint;
    int main() {
      MKMapPoint a = {1.0, 2.0};
      double *d, *e;
      d = (double *) &a;
      e = d + 1;
      printf("%f %f\n", *d, *e);
      return 0;
    }

Если какой дебил напишет такое в реальной программе...

Comment: Можно получить адрес элемента структуры и обращаться по нему через указатель. Но только зачем?

Comment: @alexlz, @mikillskegg, спасибо за ответы. У меня есть код, связанный с двумерными kd-деревьями, в котором в зависимости от чётности глубины спуска (level depth % 2) ведётся работа с x- или y-координатами соответственно. Я пытаюсь избежать многократных проверок "X или Y", и для этого изучаю, можно ли использовать обобщённый доступ к структуре MKMapPoint на основе (levelOfDepth & 1). Надеюсь, более-менее понятно описываю контекст.

Comment: @avp, я почти догадываюсь, на что Вы указываете, но можно ли, пожалуйста, примеры обращения подобной структурой?

Comment: @avp, я догадался! Можете не показывать)) Кажется, это действительно более лаконично получится - мне надо прикинуть. Как всегда, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @avp, надеюсь, Вы не возражаете, если я преобразую Ваш комментарий в ответ и приму его как правильный? Мне действительно подходит такой вариант, как наиболее удачный и изящный.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, без проблем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если код свой, то может быть окажется удобней работать с какой-то такой структурой:

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    double x, y;
  } xy;
  double axy[2];
} MKMapPoint;
```

Comment: Я наверное сегодня сильно запрограммировался уже, но вот эта специфика union в C - это очень круто! Ещё раз спасибо Вам.

Comment: @avp: Это по идее не портабельно — компилятор может использовать выравнивание.

Comment: @VladD, вот и подводные камни начались)) Это точно, что для структуры с двумя double может быть использовано выравнивание? Или это грозит для структур, в которых разные типы?

Comment: @VladD, хотите сказать, что в принципе возможна архитектура, в которой  между `xy.x` и `xy.y` будут неиспользуемые байты и `axy[1]` попадет в этот "gap", а не совместится с `xy.y`?

Лично я сомневаюсь, что нормальному инженеру придет в голову подобная идея.

Comment: @avp: ну, например, если размер double не кратен машинному слову.

Comment: @VladD, если бы речь шла о `long double`, то я бы согласился. 

(Честно говоря, с 80 и 128-bit float point дела не имел).

Answer (score 1):

На основе комментариев @alexlz и @mikillskegg и вот этого топика на StackOverflow: 
[Run through a structure and print all the values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074288/run-through-a-structure-and-print-all-the-values) я сам нашёл ответ:

```
MKMapPoint point;

double x = *((double *)(&point));
double y = *((double *)(&point) + 1);
```

Теперь мне интересно, есть ли у этого способа какие-то подводные камни?

По поводу комментария @alexlz про дебилизм подобного обращения со структурами отмечу, что беглый бенчмарк для обоих способов обращения со структурами показывает, что скорость доступа абсолютно одинаковая (Mac OS X, Clang, 100000000 значимых обращений типа ++).

Ключевой вопрос: **есть ли у этого способа доступа к структуре через указатели какие-то подводные камни, о которых мне следует знать?** (для уточнения: речь идёт именно о такой структуре, как я описал: с двумя элементами типа double, то есть элементы структуры имеют строго один и тот же тип double, и этих элементов две штуки!).

Comment: Проблема, разумеется, в выравнивании. Компилятор имеет право разместить между элементами структуры padding. Если вам и правда надо доступ в зависимости от условия, почему бы не сделать честный массив из двух элементов?

Кроме того, по стандарту это UB.

---
Думаю, комментарий @alexlz был не по поводу скорости, а по поводу несоответствия синтаксиса семантике. Если вам нужно попеременно обращаться к разным полям в зависимости от некоторого вычисленного значения, структура, возможно, не вполне правильный тип данных.

Comment: > Если вам и правда надо доступ в зависимости от условия, почему бы не сделать честный массив из двух элементов?

Спасибо, за вразумление. Я сам рассматривал этот вариант, просто интересно: неужели то, что предложил @avp не универсально для простой структуры с двумя double? (мне очень нравится изящность решения с union, хотело бы попробовать именно его).

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: насколько я понимаю, union — довольно опасная штука. В любом случае, по стандарту брать из union можно **только** значение того типа, которое туда было положено, иначе UB.

---
С другой стороны, конкретные компиляторы могут гарантировать ту или иную семантику, более сильную, чем предписывает стандарт. Что в этом смысле гарантирует clang (вы ведь на нём, да?) — надо смотреть специально. У каждого компилятора по-своему.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, правильный путь — использование [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof).

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} MKMapPoint;

const size_t MKMapPoint_x_offset = offsetof(MKMapPoint, x); // гарантированно 0
const size_t MKMapPoint_y_offset = offsetof(MKMapPoint, y);

const size_t MKMapPoint_offsets[] = { MKMapPoint_x_offset, MKMapPoint_y_offset };

double inline get_value_for_member(MKMapPoint* point, size_t index)
{
    return *(double*)((char*)point + MKMapPoint_offsets[index]);
}
```

Ну или просто

```
*(double*)((char*)point + index * MKMapPoint_y_offset)
```

если хотите.

Но лучше, на мой вкус, не пытаться перехитрить язык, а воспользоваться встроенными средствами:

```
typedef double MKMapPoint[2];
inline double MKMapPoint_get_X(MKMapPoint pt) { return pt[0]; }
inline double MKMapPoint_get_Y(MKMapPoint pt) { return pt[1]; }
```

Comment: Так! Я начинаю совсем путаться - одно решение другого изощрённее, и уже непонятно, стоит ли возвращаться к вроде бы здравой мысли про просто использования массива {x, y}. Спасибо за ответ))

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: обновил ответ.

Моё решение — более портабельный вариант идеи @avp, так что оно в любом случае вторично.