# Вопрос про касты переменных и указателей в C

Tags: c

Здравствуйте.

Этот вопрос основан на решении **@VladD** из моего предыдущего вопроса: [Возможен ли доступ к элементам struct без прямого обращения к ним через точку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/302915/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-struct-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83). В нижеследующем листинге это решение - функция `MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis1()`.

Сегодня я добавил в своём проекте флаг -Weverything, в результате чего появился такой вот варнинг:

```
Cast from 'char *' to 'double *' increases required alignment from 1 to 4
```

Я пошёл искать решение этой проблемы и нашёл 2 работающих решения, которые вместо `char *` делают касты соответственно в `uintptr_t` или `void *` - в моём листинге это соответственно функции `MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis2` и `MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis3`.

Чего я не понимаю, так это того, **почему эти решения работают**, а решения, например, с тоже 8-байтовыми `double *` и, например, `long long *` (MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis4 и MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis5) - нет.

Мой вопрос явно как-то связан с механикой кастов в С, а именно, что **на самом деле** происходит при следующих видах кастов:

```
*(double *)((char *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis])
*(double *)((uintptr_t)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis])
*(double *)((void *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis])
*(double *)((double *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis])
*(double *)((long long *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis])
```

то есть, какова механика кастов во всех этих пяти случаях?

И ещё вопрос: почему работает uintptr_t, ведь на моей системе за ним стоит обычный `unsigned long` (даже не указатель, а просто числовой тип).

P.S. В начале я думал, что дело в размере типов/указателей, отсюда и моё предположение, что должны работать `double *` и `long long *` (ведь void * же работает!), но теперь я чётко вижу, что тут дело в чём-то ещё кроме размера указателей, о чём и прошу разъяснения. Мне кажется, что ответ на этот вопрос, несмотря на специфичность его формулировки и листинга, поможет мне прояснить какие-то очень важные вещи про касты и типы в языке С.

---

**Листинг**

```
#import <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} MKMapPoint;

static const size_t MKMapPointXOffset = offsetof(MKMapPoint, x);
static const size_t MKMapPointYOffset = offsetof(MKMapPoint, y);
static const size_t MKMapPointOffsets[] = { MKMapPointXOffset, MKMapPointYOffset };

static inline double MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis1(MKMapPoint *point, int axis) {
    return *(double *)((char *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
}
static inline double MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis2(MKMapPoint *point, int axis) {
    return *(double *)((uintptr_t)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
}
static inline double MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis3(MKMapPoint *point, int axis) {
    return *(double *)((void *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
}
static inline double MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis4(MKMapPoint *point, int axis) {
    return *(double *)((double *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
}
static inline double MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis5(MKMapPoint *point, int axis) {
    return *(double *)((long long *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(MKMapPoint));
    printf("%ld %ld\n", MKMapPointXOffset, MKMapPointYOffset);

    printf("%ld %ld %ld %ld %d\n", sizeof(char *), sizeof(uintptr_t), sizeof(void *), sizeof(double *), sizeof(long long *));

    MKMapPoint x = (MKMapPoint){111, 222};

    printf("%f %f\n", MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis1(&x, 0), MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis1(&x, 1));
    printf("%f %f\n", MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis2(&x, 0), MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis2(&x, 1));
    printf("%f %f\n", MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis3(&x, 0), MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis3(&x, 1));
    printf("%f %f\n", MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis4(&x, 0), MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis4(&x, 1));
    printf("%f %f\n", MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis5(&x, 0), MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis5(&x, 1));

    return 0;
}


16
0 8
8 8 8 8 8
111.000000 222.000000
111.000000 222.000000
111.000000 222.000000
111.000000 0.000000
111.000000 0.000000
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: когда Вы пишете 

    (тип*)указатель+смещение

компилятор преобразует это в `указатель+смещение*sizeof(тип)`

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, а компьютер какой (x86 64-bit)?

Тут дело в **выравнивании адреса** (т.е. размещении переменной по адресу, кратному некоторму числу. Например, 4 или 8), которое для некоторых CPU (sparc, arm ...) *требуется* для int, long, double, void \* ... (при обращении к невыровненному int (например по адресу 0x12345) произойдет SIGBUS, а при выровненном (например 0x12344) нет), а для других CPU нет (но может *рекомендоваться* x-86).

В x-86 выровненные данные обрабатываются быстрее. 

Компилятор всегда пытается разместить переменные (в зависимости от типа) по правильному адресу.

Comment: > @Stanislaw Pankevich, а компьютер какой (x86 64-bit)?

Да. 

    Darwin Stanislaws-MacBook-Air.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Механизм возникновения предупреждения прост.

Компилятор видит, что Вы просите преобразовать указатель на char (char не требует выравнивания), который может содержать любой адрес в указатель на double (который, как считает компилятор д.б. кратен 4 (почему не 8 -- не знаю, ему тут видней)) и предупреждает, что при использовании этого адреса (**сам адрес не меняется**) для доступа к переменной типа double *могут возникнуть* проблемы.

--

Кстати, с командами типа sse (результат gcc -O3) и длинных (больше 16 байт) последовательностях int-ов в i5 действительно возникают, а в xeon -- нет.

Comment: @avp, небольшое уточнение: от 1 до 4 - это на iPhone, на Mac - от 1 до 8.

Comment: @avp, хочу поделиться с Вами ссылкой: 
[Solve the memory alignment in C interview question that stumped me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me/227900#227900). Мне показалось интересным. Вам, надеюсь, тоже будет интересно.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, спасибо, посмотрел.

Вообще, для нашей реальной жизни хватает `man posix_memalign` и знания, что для прямой работы с `raw device` буфер надо выравнивать на PAGESIZE.

Comment: Да, там в комментариях posix_memalign упоминается... Спасибо за дополнение. Я вряд ли с таким столкнулсь в ближайшее время, но для общего развития... это очень познавательно))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я прочитал несколько текстов и сделал несколько тестов и теперь, похоже, могу более или менее корректно ответить на все свои вопросы.

Как выяснилось, правильным и стабильным является ответ, который использует **uintptr_t**:

```
*(double *)((uintptr_t)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis])
```

Причины этого описаны подробно ниже в моих ответах на собственные вопросы.

---

> Чего я не понимаю, так это того, почему эти решения работают, а решения, например, с тоже 8-байтовыми double * и, например, long long * (MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis4 и MKMapPointGetCoordinateForAxis5) - нет.

Если кратко: то неработающие решения не работают потому, что их размер их типов - **8**  (не указателей, а именно самих типов!), и потому за операцией **+ MKMapPointOffsets[axis]** на самом деле скрывается **+ MKMapPointOffsets[axis] * sizeof(double или long long)**, то есть **MKMapPointOffsets[axis] * 8**, что каждый раз выбрасывает эти неработающие решения за границы структуры.

Более развёрнуто:

Действительно, как правильно указал @KoVadim:

> (тип *)указатель+смещение
>
> компилятор преобразует это в указатель + смещение * sizeof(тип)

В целом, я так и понимал эту арифметику, просто почему-то именно в этом случае мне ошибочно казалось, что должно быть **sizeof(тип *)**, откуда и возникало недоумение по поводу того, что **double *** и **long long *** не работают, ведь у них **sizeof** равен **8** также как и у **uintptr_t и `char ***.

После того, как я уловил эту свою ошибку, всё встало на свои места:

Вот размеры структуры и соответствующих отступов для x и y координат:

```
printf("%ld\n", sizeof(MKMapPoint));
printf("%ld %ld\n", MKMapPointXOffset, MKMapPointYOffset);

16
0 8
```

То есть **x** имеет смещение **0** относительно указателя на структуру, а **y** соответственно - **8**.

Посмотрим ещё раз на исходное решение @VladD:

```
return *(double *)((char *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
```

Я только сегодня окончательно разобрался с тем, зачем тут нужен каст в (char *): а именно он нужен для того, чтобы при прибавлении отступа он умножался на sizeof(char), то есть единицу. В результате мы и получаем: "указатель на структуру + отступ-соответствующей-координаты".

---

> Почему работает void *?

На самом деле решение с **void *** нельзя считать подходящим, так как оно выдаёт другой варнинг:

```
Arithmetic on a pointer to void is a GNU extension
```

но для понимания оказалось важно, что работает оно также, как и char * по той причине, что в случае, когда это extension доступно, то **sizeof(void)** равняется 1.

Об этом очень интересный комментарий здесь: [sizeof(void) equals 1 in C? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350650/598057).

Откуда опять получается, что за выражением

```
return *(double *)((void *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
```

стоит (это уже сейчас будет псевдокод)

```
return *(double *)((void *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis] * sizeof(void));
```

то есть мы снова получаем отступ **0 для х** и **8 для y**.

---

> И ещё вопрос: почему работает uintptr_t, ведь на моей системе за ним стоит обычный unsigned long (даже не указатель, а просто числовой тип).

Ответить на этот вопрос мне оказалось интереснее всего, потому что это решение отличается от остальных рабочих: с **char *** и с **void ***.

Это решение не использует адресную арифметику для работы с указателями, оно просто берёт указатель на начало структуры, превращает его в число и добавляет к этому числу **0 или 8** в зависимости от  x это или y:

```
return *(double *)((uintptr_t)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);
```

То есть в данном случае происходит обычное сложение двух чисел (нет умножения на sizeof, как это было бы в случае с указателями).

Это возможно потому, что uintptr_t обладает замечательным свойством ([What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846648/598057)):

> In C99, it is defined as "an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer".

То есть, другими словами, можно быть уверенными в том, что мы делаем каст адреса в число, которое имеет тот же размер, что и размер этого адреса.

---

Ниже следует перечень тестов, которые навели меня на верные мысли (надеюсь, я нигде не ошибся).

И ещё позже я нашёл интересный топик на другую тему, но в котором тоже очень интересным образом используется **uintptr_t**: [Solve the memory alignment in C interview question that stumped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227897/solve-the-memory-alignment-in-c-interview-question-that-stumped-me).

P.S. Спасибо @KoVadim и @avp за ценные интересные комментарии как к вопросу, так и к ответу.

---

Тесты и логи:

```
printf("\nTesting offsets:\n\n");

printf("%ld %ld\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(void));

printf("%p\n", (&x));
printf("%p\n", (&x + 1));

printf("%p\n", ((char *)&x));
printf("%p\n", ((char *)&x + 1));

printf("%p\n", ((void *)&x));
printf("%p\n", ((void *)&x + 1));

printf("%p\n", ((uintptr_t)&x));
printf("%p\n", ((uintptr_t)&x + 1));

uintptr_t ptr = (uintptr_t)&x;

printf("%p %p %p\n", &x, ptr, (void *)ptr);

printf("%lu\n", (&x));
printf("%lu\n", ((uintptr_t)&x));

Testing offsets:

1 1
0x7fff5fbffa10
0x7fff5fbffa20
0x7fff5fbffa10
0x7fff5fbffa11
0x7fff5fbffa10
0x7fff5fbffa11
0x7fff5fbffa10
0x7fff5fbffa11
0x7fff5fbffa10 0x7fff5fbffa10 0x7fff5fbffa10
140734799804944
140734799804944
```

Comment: да, рассуждения похожи на правду. В линуксе gcc с c++ не может справиться с приведением к (void*).

Зато теперь Вы хорошо знаете арифметику указателей :).

Comment: Насчет рассуждений согласен с @KoVadim. 

--

А вот утверждение о `(void *)` (если Вы про это)

        return *(double *)((void *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);

сам gcc не подтверждает.

--

Еще ему не нравится неконстантная инициализация

    static const size_t MKMapPointOffsets[] = { MKMapPointXOffset, MKMapPointYOffset };

прагма (?) `#import` и отсутствие ряда инклюдов.

В результате пришлось заменить

    static const size_t MKMapPointXOffset = offsetof(MKMapPoint, x);
    static const size_t MKMapPointYOffset = offsetof(MKMapPoint, y);

на макросы из `offsetof()`

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, наверное я как-то криво написал. 

С gcc **все** результаты точно, как у Вас (даже ошибочные нули)

    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc c.c
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
    16
    0 8
    8 8 8 8 8
    111.000000 222.000000
    111.000000 222.000000
    111.000000 222.000000
    111.000000 0.000000
    111.000000 0.000000
    avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ 

Т.е. для gcc приведение к `void *` в смысле *адресной арифметики* совпадает с приведением к `char *`.

Comment: @avp, спасибо, теперь всё встало на места! Но всё равно остаётся вопрос по поводу утверждения @KoVadim: что может быть такого в вариантах/версиях gcc или Linux, что приведёт к тому, что он "не справится" с приведением? В смысле мне интересно вообще про поведение void * -- как оно может меняться от системы к системе (если про это, конечно, есть какие-то более-менее сложившиеся сведения).

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, я использую `void *`, когда мне надо хранить или передавать *просто абстрактный адрес*.

Перед любым его использованием я всегда привожу его к адресу на конкретный тип данных (подходящий по смыслу задачи).

Comment: Вот это очень понятно - "когда мне надо хранить или передавать просто абстрактный адрес" и "перед использованием я всегда привожу его у указателю на конкретный тип". Особенно мне это понятно теперь: в связи с данным моим вопросом, в контексте улучшенного понимания адресной арифметики)) Спасибо за внимание и ответы!

Comment: по поводу `void*` - я же не даром написал - с++. Потому что на нем тестил.

Стандарт говорит о том, что void* имеет размер, что бы сохранить любой указатель, поэтому разработчики вправе сделать его хоть 16 байт на 32битной системе. В с++ `void*` может быть в два раза больше разрядности (64 и 128 бит соответственно), если в нем храниться указатель на функцию метода (вроде так, нужно проверить).

Comment: @KoVadim, тогда, если я правильно понимаю "Стандарт говорит о том, что void* имеет размер, что бы сохранить любой указатель", 

вот это

    return *(double *)((void *)point + MKMapPointOffsets[axis]);

всегда нормально сработает при условии что GNU extension позволяет нам делать pointer arithmetic с void *, каким бы ни был размер void *, правильно?

Comment: нет, неправильно понимаете. Раз стандарт не гарантирует размер `void*`, то делать какую-то арифметику с ним опасно. А вот у самого void размер вообще не имеет смысла. Да, некоторые компиляторы это пропускают и генерируют чудо-код. И он даже работает. Но то, что он будет нормально работать - нет гарантий.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо! Чётко и ясно - "делать какую-то арифметику с void * опасно".